# Azure Maps and SQL AT TIME ZONE incompatible time zone for Hawaii

Tags: sql-server, azure, timezone, azure-maps

I just ran into an issue when using data that Azure Maps provides for timezones to attempt to get local time in SQL Server (Azure SQL) using `AT TIME ZONE`.

When I provide the lat/long data to Azure Maps for the Hawaiian location, the return says "Hawaii-Aleutian Standard Time":

```
"Names":{  
        "ISO6391LanguageCode":"en",
        "Generic":"Hawaii-Aleutian Time",
        "Standard":"Hawaii-Aleutian Standard Time",
        "Daylight":"Hawaii-Aleutian Daylight Time"
     },
```

In another part of my system I need the ability to determine a local time for that location in SQL Server so I am using `AT TIME ZONE` and injecting the Standard timezone. This works great for the US Timezones that I'm dealing with such as "Eastern Standard Time" or "Central Standard Time". When it gets to a Hawaiian location... it errors out and says that it isn't a valid time zone.

Reviewing the lists of timezones I've been able to find online for SQL Server it appears that Hawaii's timezone in SQL is "Hawaiian Standard Time".

Has anyone else run into this disconnect?

I'm thinking I will need to right some exception code to replace this Azure provided timezone with "Hawaiian Standard Time". Is there a better solution?

For reference here's a sample URL (minus key): `https://atlas.microsoft.com/timezone/byCoordinates/json?subscription-key={key}&api-version=1.0&options=all&query=21.4500,-158.0054`

Here's the full JSON returned:

```
{
  "Version": "2018g",
  "ReferenceUtcTimestamp": "2018-12-08T17:10:31.8007137Z",
  "TimeZones": [
    {
      "Id": "Pacific/Honolulu",
      "Aliases": [
        "Pacific/Johnston",
        "US/Hawaii"
      ],
      "Countries": [
        {
          "Name": "United States",
          "Code": "US"
        },
        {
          "Name": "US minor outlying islands",
          "Code": "UM"
        }
      ],
      "Names": {
        "ISO6391LanguageCode": "en",
        "Generic": "Hawaii-Aleutian Time",
        "Standard": "Hawaii-Aleutian Standard Time",
        "Daylight": "Hawaii-Aleutian Daylight Time"
      },
      "ReferenceTime": {
        "Tag": "HST",
        "StandardOffset": "-10:00:00",
        "DaylightSavings": "00:00:00",
        "WallTime": "2018-12-08T07:10:31.8007137-10:00",
        "PosixTzValidYear": 2018,
        "PosixTz": "HST+10"
      },
      "RepresentativePoint": {
        "Latitude": 21.306944444444444,
        "Longitude": -157.85833333333332
      },
      "TimeTransitions": [
        {
          "Tag": "HST",
          "StandardOffset": "-10:00:00",
          "DaylightSavings": "00:00:00",
          "UtcStart": "1947-06-08T12:30:00Z",
          "UtcEnd": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Not that I see. Running `select * from sys.time_zone_info where name like '%Hawaii%';` shows 'Hawaiian Standard Time' as you found via other methods. It sure would be good if MS products agreed with each other.

Comment: There are two commonly used sets of time zone codes. The Azure Maps platform provides both IANA and Windows time zone codes. SQL only supports Windows time zone codes. Can you provide the URL query you are using as I'm not sure how to reproduce the results you are seeing (exclude your key of course).

Comment: As far as I can tell it only returns one set and it doesn't correspond with SQL's set. I updated the question with a sample URL and the returned JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, "Pacific/Honolulu" is the IANA code. According to some SQL docs it supports all Windows time zones while other docs say it only supports the time zones in the registry of the machine, which can vary from machine to machine. Physically checking my machine I can see SQL supports 137 time zones (Select * from sys.time_zone_info). However, according to Windows docs, it has 250 default time zones (plus a bunch of extended ones). There is definitely a disconnect some where but it is looking more like a Windows/SQL disconnect.

That said, it appears that "Hawaiian Standard Time" and "Hawaii-Aleutian Standard Time" are the same: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/hast

However when it comes to daylight savings it gets much more complex: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/hadt

I'll pass this thread on to the Azure Maps engineering and data team for deeper investigation.

Comment: I appreciate your investigation and response on this question. I put logic in place in my application to replace the zones when necessary so the code can support this scenario. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

The strings returned in the `Names` section are not identifiers.  They are localized strings that originate in the [Unicode CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/), and are intended for display to end users.  While some of them might align to identifiers when presented in English, there's no guarantee of that.

They aren't chosen arbitrarily either.  "Hawaii-Aleutian Time" is indeed the legal name of this time zone, as defined by 15 USC 260 ([and described on Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_States#United_States_time_zones)).

On the other hand, SQL Server's time zone functionality relies strictly on Windows time zone identifiers, as can be found in the Windows registry, or by various APIs (such as .NET's `TimeZoneInfo.Id`) and command line utilities (such as on the first line of each pair of results returned by `TZUTIL /L`).

Unfortunately, it appears that the Azure Maps API currently only returns the IANA ID, not the corresponding Windows ID.  I've asked the Azure Maps API team to consider adding this in a future release.

In the meantime, you can convert the IANA ID to the corresponding Windows ID before using it in SQL Server.  The easiest way to do this, assuming you're in a .NET application, is to use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library:

```
string tz = TZConvert.IanaToWindows("Pacific/Honolulu");  //=>  "Hawaiian Standard Time"
```

If you're not in .NET, you can use the file built into Windows at the path:

```
C:\Windows\Globalization\Time Zone\timezoneMapping.xml
```

The file has entries that look like this:

```xml
<MapTZ TZID="Pacific/Honolulu" WinID="Hawaiian Standard Time" Region="001" Default="true" StdPath="Hawaii_Aleutian/standard" DltPath="Hawaii_Aleutian/daylight" />
```

You would just use the `TZID` and `WinID` attributes to do the mapping in that direction.

Alternatively, you could use the CLDR's `/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml` file, as this is the authoritative source.  The dev trunk version is located [here](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).  Its data looks similar, but the attributes are named differently:

```xml
<mapZone other="Hawaiian Standard Time" territory="001" type="Pacific/Honolulu"/>
```